# samsung galaxy emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I couldn't even find a developer site for Samsung.  Is it possible to get a galaxy emulator?  I do not want a skin; I want the full emulation including the Samsung TouchWiz.

Comment: developer site link: http://developer.samsung.com/

Answer (score 6):

Emulation of Android on a computer is available through using the SDK. Lifehacker have a good walkthrough of setting up a virtual emulation of an Android device on a Windows machine here: http://lifehacker.com/5587260/how-to-test-drive-android-on-your-pc-without-buying-a-phone . This should cover the emulation of Android, but TouchWiz might be a little more difficult.

These virtual devices are full installs of the Android operating system, and if there is a way of installing TouchWiz on a normal Android phone (try searching for 'TouchWiz for Froyo') it will be possible to install it on a virtual phone. You can install applications in apk files using 'adb', a debug tool. A quick search of 'install apk with adb' should yield many results.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks aSemy... but I had understood all that.  We have another company developing the Android app, and we are seeing some odd behavior on first an HTC.  Then I installed it on a Motorola emulator and saw similar but different behavior.  There were the two main "ui customizations" that I knew of, but after more research I also heard of Samsung TouchWiz.

Comment: Where did you find a motorola emulator?

Comment: @Janusz http://developer.motorola.com/tools/resources/

Answer (score 0):

There is a skin for the galaxy s2

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9578

change in the manifest.ini file level 10 and put the zip
android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-10\skins\Galaxy_S2

Comment: This merely shows a Samsung Galaxy S2 frame around the emulated device — it's still stock, Google, Android on the emulated device itself